# Why does the subsection appear in the header before it does in the document?

Tags: sectioning

I am using this code

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\lhead{\textit{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textit{\rightmark}}
\rfoot{\textit{Page \thepage}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\xdef\leftmark{\thesection\quad#1}\xdef\rightmark{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\xdef\rightmark{\thesubsection\quad#1}}
```

to print the subsection title in the header. However, I have the issue that if the subsection is printed at the top of the page, then it shows in the header of the previous page. This is shown below.
[image]

This is Section 1.1, but the header shows Section 1.2. How do I fix this? My current solution is to do the following.

```
\begin{Def}
Let $\{M_i:i \in \{1,\ldots ,k\} \}$ be a family of submodules of an $R$-module $M$. Then $M$ is the \textit{direct sum} of $M_1,\ldots ,M_k$ if\\
\indent  i) $M=M_1\oplus \ldots \oplus M_k\coloneqq \{ m_1+\ldots +m_k: m_i \in M_i\}$; \\
\indent  ii) $M_i \cap M_j = \emptyset $ for all $i \neq j$.
\end{Def} 

\newpage
```

So I just add a `\newpage` command at the end of the page and that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, replace `\xdef\leftmark` by `\markboth`, and `\xdef\rightmark` by `\markright`, so that the two lines re-defining `\sectionmark` and `\subsectionmark` would be like this:

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\quad#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\quad#1}}
```

Comment: This causes errors in the document because ```argument of \markright has an extra }.```

Comment: I can't see where that extra `}`

Comment: I assume the error was that you forgot the second argument for ```\markboth```. So it should be ```{\markboth{\thesection\quad#1}{} \markright{}}```. Well I think so anyway, as that has fixed both problems